# Qt5 programs won't compile

Tags: qt

I'm trying to get Qt5 working on Ubuntu 12.04. I downloaded the 32-bit installer from http://qt-project.org/downloads and basically just let it install everything in my home folder.

I had to add ~/Qt/5.1.0/gcc/bin to my path for qmake to work, but now when I try to make a hello qt example (using qt4 book), when running make, it cannot find the `QApplication` or `QLabel` header. When I replace them with `QtWidgets/QApplication`, it finds the header, but I get all undefined references when linking.

This is the command make executes:

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../../../Qt/5.1.0/gcc/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I. -I../../../../Qt/5.1.0/gcc/include -I../../../../Qt/5.1.0/gcc/include/QtGui -I../../../../Qt/5.1.0/gcc/include/QtCore -I. -o hello.o hello.C
```

I managed to figure out that it's `qmake -project` that is doing something wrong. When I make an app in Qt Creator (which actually works), the .pro file has lines like `QT += widgets`, that are not there when I run it on the command line.

Comment: I managed to figure out that it's qmake -project that is doing something wrong. When I make an app in Qt Creator (which actually works), the .pro file has lines like 'QT += widgets', that are not there when I run it on the command line. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer using `qmake --help`. This actually says:

> Note: The created .pro file probably will 
>                    need to be edited. For example add the QT variable to 
>                    specify what modules are required.

Adding these lines to the .pro file solved the problem:

```
QT += core gui
QT += widgets
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to manually editing the .pro file after running `qmake -project`, you can specify assignments on the command line that will be included in the generated files:

```
qmake -project "QT = core gui widgets"
```

See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/qmake-running.html